# Оптимальное решение для игры "Пятнашки"

Tags: алгоритм

Передо мной стоит задача поиска оптимального решения для игры пятнашки (если оно существует). То есть имеется разобранная комбинация, и за минимально возможное количество ходов нужно её привести к начальной (т.е. найти последовательность шагов).
Если использовать рекурсивный полный перебор, то он очень быстро загнётся. Скажите, существует ли алгоритм решения, и если да, то какой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Со стороны трудно понять, в чём принципиальная сложность алгоритма.

1. Существует 16! = 2 * 10<sup>13</sup> исходных позиций, из которых половина неразрешима.
2. По моим оценкам, за 4 хода пустая клетка может оказаться на одном из 7 мест, и при этом создаётся в среднем 36 разных позиций. Т.е. за 2n ходов возникает 6<sup>n</sup> позиций.
3. Поскольку 6<sup>16</sup> = 2,8 * 10<sup>13</sup>, то весь пасьянс не должен занять более 32 ходов.
4. Несложная программка позволит сформировать массив примерно на 60 миллионов позиций (в котором пустая клетка может находиться на одном из 8 мест), из которых можно добраться к финишу ровно за 20 ходов (20 шагов алгоритма Дейкстры), и записать для каждой из них оптимальные траектории пустой клетки.
5. Перебором не глубже 12 шагов (примерно 200000 позиций) из произвольной начальной позиции должна достигаться одна из позиций массива.
6. Остальное - непринципиальные детали.