# Поиск оптимального решения в игре пятнашки (puzzle 15) (поле 3 на 3)

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, puzzle

Стоит задача найти оптимальное решение для игры пятнашки puzzle 15 для игрового поля 3 на 3, в принципе мне кажется что программа практически готова, но есть одно маленькое но: решается только простые состояния где требуется малое кол-во перестановок, к примеру { 1, 2, 3,   4, 5, 6,   0, 7, 8 };
более сложные же (например { 1, 0, 2,   4, 6, 3,   7, 5, 8 };) не приходят к решению так как можно сказать что программа забивается в угол и не может оттуда выйти
вот я и не могу никак понять где что подправить чтобы программы выходила из таких ситуаций
также не совсем понял какой тип указать при возврате массива из функции поэтому поставил auto

```
auto from_vector_to_array(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int len = N;
    int vec_array[N][N];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            vec_array[i][j] = this_vector[count];
            ++count;
        }
    return vec_array;
}
```

метрика самая простая, двигаюсь в ту сторону где наименьшее кол-во стоящих на своих местах элементов

код онлайн https://rextester.com/live/LWLCPI90421

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

#define N 3

using namespace std;

int max_depth = 100;
bool is_solved = false;

auto from_vector_to_array(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int len = N;
    int vec_array[N][N];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            vec_array[i][j] = this_vector[count];
            ++count;
        }
    return vec_array;
}

// A utility function to count inversions in given 
// array 'arr[]'. Note that this function can be 
// optimized to work in O(n Log n) time. The idea 
// here is to keep code small and simple. 
int getInvCount(int arr[])
{
    int inv_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N * N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N * N; j++)
        {
            // count pairs(i, j) such that i appears 
            // before j, but i > j. 
            if (arr[j] && arr[i] && arr[i] > arr[j])
                inv_count++;
        }
    }
    return inv_count;
}

// find Position of blank from bottom 
int findXPosition(int puzzle[N][N])
{
    // start from bottom-right corner of matrix 
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        for (int j = N - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if (puzzle[i][j] == 0)
                return N - i;
}

// This function returns true if given 
// instance of N*N - 1 puzzle is solvable 
bool isSolvable(int puzzle[N][N])
{
    // Count inversions in given puzzle 
    int invCount = getInvCount((int*)puzzle);

    // If grid is odd, return true if inversion 
    // count is even. 
    if (N & 1)
        return !(invCount & 1);

    else     // grid is even 
    {
        int pos = findXPosition(puzzle);
        if (pos & 1)
            return !(invCount & 1);
        else
            return invCount & 1;
    }
}

int find_index_number(vector <int> &this_vector, const int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this_vector.size(); ++i) {
        if (number == this_vector[i])
            return i;
    }
}

void go_right(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(this_vector, 0);
    if (zero_index == 0 || zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 6 || zero_index == 7) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[1]);
            break;
        case 1:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[2]);
            break;
        case 3:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[4]);
            break;
        case 4:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[5]);
            break;
        case 6:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[7]);
            break;
        case 7:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[8]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void go_left(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(this_vector, 0);
    if (zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 2 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5 || zero_index == 7 || zero_index == 8) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 1:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[1]);
            break;
        case 4:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[3]);
            break;
        case 5:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[4]);
            break;
        case 7:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[6]);
            break;
        case 8:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[7]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void go_down(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(this_vector, 0);
    if (zero_index == 0 || zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 2 || zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[3]);
            break;
        case 1:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[4]);
            break;
        case 2:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[5]);
            break;
        case 3:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[6]);
            break;
        case 4:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[7]);
            break;
        case 5:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[8]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void go_up(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(this_vector, 0);
    if (zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5 || zero_index == 6 || zero_index == 7 || zero_index == 8) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 3:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[0]);
        case 4:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[1]);
        case 5:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[2]);
        case 6:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[3]);
        case 7:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[4]);
        case 8:
            swap(this_vector[zero_index], this_vector[5]);
        }
    }
}

bool is_state_identical(vector <int> first_vector, vector  <int> second_vector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < first_vector.size(); i++) {
        if (first_vector[i] != second_vector[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void display_state(vector <int> &this_vector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this_vector.size(); i++) {
        cout << this_vector[i] << ' ';
        if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8) cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //cout << ".";
}

bool check_history(vector <int> &this_vector, vector <vector <int>> &history) {
    if (history.size() == 0) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < history.size(); ++i) {
            if (this_vector == history[i]) return true;
        }
    return false;
}

int amount_unmatching_left(vector <int> &start_vector, vector <int> &final_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(start_vector, 0);
    int count = 0;
    if (zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 2 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5 || zero_index == 7 || zero_index == 8) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            if (start_vector[0] != final_vector[0]) ++count;
        case 1:
            if (start_vector[1] != final_vector[1]) ++count;
        case 3:
            if (start_vector[3] != final_vector[3]) ++count;
        case 4:
            if (start_vector[4] != final_vector[4]) ++count;
        case 6:
            if (start_vector[6] != final_vector[6]) ++count;
        case 7:
            if (start_vector[7] != final_vector[7]) ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int amount_unmatching_right(vector <int> &start_vector, vector <int> &final_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(start_vector, 0);
    int count = 0;
    if (zero_index == 0 || zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 6 || zero_index == 7) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            if (start_vector[1] != final_vector[1]) ++count;
        case 1:
            if (start_vector[2] != final_vector[2]) ++count;
        case 3:
            if (start_vector[4] != final_vector[4]) ++count;
        case 4:
            if (start_vector[5] != final_vector[5]) ++count;
        case 6:
            if (start_vector[7] != final_vector[7]) ++count;
        case 7:
            if (start_vector[8] != final_vector[8]) ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int amount_unmatching_up(vector <int> &start_vector, vector <int> &final_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(start_vector, 0);
    int count = 0;
    if (zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5 || zero_index == 6 || zero_index == 7 || zero_index == 8) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            if (start_vector[0] != final_vector[0]) ++count;
        case 1:
            if (start_vector[1] != final_vector[1]) ++count;
        case 3:
            if (start_vector[2] != final_vector[2]) ++count;
        case 4:
            if (start_vector[3] != final_vector[3]) ++count;
        case 6:
            if (start_vector[4] != final_vector[4]) ++count;
        case 7:
            if (start_vector[5] != final_vector[5]) ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int amount_unmatching_down(vector <int> &start_vector, vector <int> &final_vector) {
    int zero_index = find_index_number(start_vector, 0);
    int count = 0;
    if (zero_index == 0 || zero_index == 1 || zero_index == 2 || zero_index == 3 || zero_index == 4 || zero_index == 5) {
        switch (zero_index) {
        case 0:
            if (start_vector[3] != final_vector[3]) ++count;
        case 1:
            if (start_vector[4] != final_vector[4]) ++count;
        case 3:
            if (start_vector[5] != final_vector[5]) ++count;
        case 4:
            if (start_vector[6] != final_vector[6]) ++count;
        case 6:
            if (start_vector[7] != final_vector[7]) ++count;
        case 7:
            if (start_vector[8] != final_vector[8]) ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void find_solution(vector <int> &current_vector, vector <int> &final_vector, int deepth, vector <vector <int>> &history) {
    srand(time(0));

    if (deepth > max_depth || is_solved == true)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    if (is_state_identical(current_vector, final_vector)) {
        cout << "State was solved" << endl;
        cout << "Depth=" << deepth << endl;

        display_state(current_vector);
        is_solved = true;
        exit(0);
    }

    //int where_to_go = rand() % 4;
    int where_to_go, left, right, up, down, maximum;

    left = amount_unmatching_left(current_vector, final_vector);
    right = amount_unmatching_right(current_vector, final_vector);
    up = amount_unmatching_up(current_vector, final_vector);
    down = amount_unmatching_down(current_vector, final_vector);

    maximum = max(max(max(left, right), up), down);
    if (maximum == left) where_to_go = 0;
    if (maximum == right) where_to_go = 1;
    if (maximum == up) where_to_go = 2;
    if (maximum == down) where_to_go = 3;

    vector <int> temp_vector(current_vector.size()*current_vector.size());
    switch (where_to_go)
    {
    case 0:
        temp_vector = current_vector;
        go_left(temp_vector);
        if (!check_history(temp_vector, history)) {
            current_vector = temp_vector;
            history.push_back(current_vector);
            display_state(current_vector);
        }
        find_solution(current_vector, final_vector, deepth + 1, history);
    case 1:
        temp_vector = current_vector;
        go_right(temp_vector);
        if (!check_history(temp_vector, history)) {
            current_vector = temp_vector;
            history.push_back(current_vector);
            display_state(current_vector);
        }
        find_solution(current_vector, final_vector, deepth + 1, history);
    case 2:
        temp_vector = current_vector;
        go_up(temp_vector);
        if (!check_history(temp_vector, history)) {
            current_vector = temp_vector;
            history.push_back(current_vector);
            display_state(current_vector);
        }
        find_solution(current_vector, final_vector, deepth + 1, history);
    case 3:
        temp_vector = current_vector;
        go_down(temp_vector);
        if (!check_history(temp_vector, history)) {
            current_vector = temp_vector;
            history.push_back(current_vector);
            display_state(current_vector);
        }
        find_solution(current_vector, final_vector, deepth + 1, history);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    vector <int> start_state(size*size);
    vector <int> final_state(size*size);
    vector <vector <int>> history;
    final_state = { 1, 2, 3,   4, 5, 6,   7, 8, 0 };

    //start_state = { 1, 0, 2,   4, 6, 3,   7, 5, 8 };
    start_state = { 1, 2, 3,   4, 5, 6,   0, 7, 8 };

    display_state(start_state);

    if (isSolvable(from_vector_to_array(start_state))) {
        cout << "State is Solvabale!" << endl;
        find_solution(start_state, final_state, 0, history);
    }
    else {
        cout << "State is Unsolvable!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    //cout << amount_unmatching_left(start_state, final_state) << " " << amount_unmatching_right(start_state, final_state) << " " << amount_unmatching_up(start_state, final_state) << " " << amount_unmatching_down(start_state, final_state);

}
```

Comment: по поводу возвращаемого значения - не совсем понятно зачем оно вообще нужно, ведь это вектор, который был подан на вход. Так что сдесь лучше просто поставить `void`. Auto в таких случаях лучше не ставить из-за непоняток с возвращаемым типом (я даже точно не могу утверждать что будет возвращено: ссылка или вектор, но больше склоняюсь к вектору).

Comment: Мне представляется, что тут слишком много кода для такой (относительной простой) задачи. При чем большая часть - лютая копипаста Вот зачем перед каждым `switch` блок `if` проверяющий те же самые индексы? А в каждом `case` происходит доступ по индексу, отличающемуся на 1. Напишите функцию для перемещения блока в произвольное место.

Comment: добавил вот такую штуку
if (prev_vector == current_vector) {
  srand(time(0));
  where_to_go = rand() % 4;
 }
перед запуском основого свича с перестановкой, и если я запускуаю в этом месте точку остановки и поэтапно двигаюсь по программе то все отлично перемещается, а если без точки остановки то как и раньше программа забивается в угол, либо двигается на 5-6 шагов дальше, дублирующий иф убрал, и правда он был лишним

Answer (score 1):

### В полной общности задача является NP-полной.

Для вашего случай можно поступить одним из двух вариантов:

1. [Алгоритм имитации отжига](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0) (или его аналоги, например [генетические алгоритмы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)). Но этот подход не даст оптимального решения, даст лишь "достаточно хорошее".
2. Анализ графа игры (есть оценка на максимальную длину решения, до этой глубины и следует перебирать). Для случая 3 на 3 вполне допустим полный перебор, и этот вариант сработает. Для бОльших размеров поля уже лучше воспользоваться предыдущим вариантом.

Неплохо про это игру написано в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B2_15), очень рекомендую ознакомиться с данной статьёй. Также про ваш случай можно почитать [тут](https://www.dokwork.ru/2012/03/blog-post.html), я не сильно вникал, но по-моему человек полностью решает задачу, и даже привод код (правда не на плюсах).

Также обратите внимание на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99872/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8) вопрос stackoverflow, приведённый ответ может помочь.